# Untar a filesystem to device as normal user but maintaining the correct UID and GID

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, embedded, ext4

I'm doing quite a bit of development using Yocto to target an embedded system.

As its final output, Yocto generates a tarball of the filesystem, which I then untar onto an ext4 partition of an SD card, which becomes the root filesystem of the embedded system.

In order to set all the permissions correctly on the SD card ext4 partition, I'm currently untarring the file using sudo, which means repeated operations deleting files and so on with root privileges - it's only a matter of time before I accidentally delete some system files due to an erroneous / or something.

Clearly I only need root with respect to the embedded filesystem, not my own machine.

Is there some way to untar the file as a normal user and end up with the correct UIDs on the resultant filesystem? It would be fine to change the way the device is mounted if that solves the problem. Or perhaps some chroot trick?

Comment: I am not familiar with their usage myself, but [Linux Capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) look promising.

Comment: @FelixDietrich thanks for that. I took a look, but it doesn't seem to obvious!

Comment: I played around with it a bit: I can untar an archive and set owner and permissions as normal user when I give tar the *cap_chown* and *cap_fowner* capabilities (`setcap "cap_chown+ep cap_fowner+ep" /bin/tar`; remove with `setcap -r /bin/tar`). Problem is: you have not contained *tar* to a path, and – if I understand capabilities correctly – *tar* can now set owner, permission, attributes of any file on your system regardless of access rights. One could try and contain *tar* with [apparmor](http://apparmor.net/) or [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org), but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Thanks @FelixDietrich. I'm currently thinking that the "correct" solution for this is something around [fakeroot](https://wiki.debian.org/FakeRoot).

Comment: I don't think that *fakeroot* will help you when unpacking the archive: while you might not get errors when *tar* uses *chown*/*chmod* it will not **actually** succeed setting owner and permissions on the real system outside the *fakeroot* environment.

Comment: Hmm interesting. You're quite right of course. Using apparmor to restrict global capabilities seems a bit of a brute force approach (also, one of those system tweaks you make and forget and then spend a day relearning when you buy a new machine). Given I could (with suitable permissions on the device) poke bits directly on a piece of hardware, which could be an SD card, I feel there _must_ be a way to do this without making far reaching system changes.

Comment: Maybe you could use *chroot* and a statically linked *tar* in the new root directory?

Comment: I played around with using *chroot*. Instead of compiling *tar* statically linked I downloaded a [busybox binary](https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/) and put it as well as the archive to extract into the chroot directory. Then I ran the following command: `chroot /tmp/chroot-test/ /busybox tar --xz -xvf archive.tar.xz`. (I chose the busybox binary because *GNU tar* executes e.g. *xz* which than also has to be available in the PATH statically linked.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `tar`'s `-p` option is what you're looking for?

From `man 1 tar`:

> -p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
>   extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)

`--numeric-owner` and `--xattrs` may also be of interest:

> --numeric-owner
>   Always use numbers for user/group names.
>
> --xattrs
>   Enable extended attributes support.

Comment: The problem is creating with the correct permission in the first place.